# Removing Mail Original Message using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**Email:**

Hello World 123 123

---

```
From: uSER001 [user001@yahoo.com]
Sent: Thursday, July 19, 2013 11:21 PM
To: ts@yahoo.com
Subject: Re: Ticketing System
```

Can be anything sd asd asd asd asda dasdasd asda asd

---

```
From: Ticketing System [ts@yahoo.com]
Sent: Thursday, July 19, 2013 11:21 PM
To: uSER001, uSER002
Subject: Ticketing System
```

Content From Ticketing System

---

Ticketing System http://www.yahoo.com

**Output Should be:**
Hello World 123 123

---

```
From: uSER001 [user001@yahoo.com]
Sent: Thursday, July 19, 2013 11:21 PM
To: ts@yahoo.com
Subject: Re: Ticketing System
```

Can be anything sd asd asd asd asda dasdasd asda asd

**--**
Is this possible using `preg_match($pattern,$data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)` and `substr`?

Comment: The headers attached to emails can be long and varied. It's not likely you can do this with a regular expression. Rather, you'll need to parse the content line by line with PHP

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use preg_match to parse mail message reliably. Better use a [**PHP Mime Mail Parser**](https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/) for this task. Using Mime Mail Parser code will be as simple as:

```
require_once('MimeMailParser.class.php');

$path = 'path/to/mail.txt';

$Parser = new MimeMailParser();
$Parser->setPath($path);

$to       = $Parser->getHeader('to');
$from     = $Parser->getHeader('from');
$subject  = $Parser->getHeader('subject');
$textBody = $Parser->getMessageBody('text');
$htmlBody = $Parser->getMessageBody('html');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using ews to get the emails. I need to remove the original message from the textbody

Comment: You can keep using ews, `PHP Mime Mail Parser` is tiny PHP code for parsing individual email components.